# Can two magnetars collide?

Tags: magnetic-fields, gravitational-waves, neutron-stars

Kilonova occurs when neutron stars inspiral and smash into each other releasing gigantic gravitational waves and materials, what about when their subsets were to collide? Would the powerful magnetic field be able to keep them at bay? Assume their masses to be identical at 1.4 solar masses also what happens to the magnetic field post kilonova?